# Is there any way to replace methods in super class without losing the old definition?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to replace `a` function in super class `A` in order to extend its functionality in `B` class, but without losing the old definition. So is there any way to force the `A::b` method to use a new definition from `B` class? I have experience in Java, so I know it is possible in this language. Expected output is

```
A::b
B::a
A::a
```

Current output is

```
A::b
A::a
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
    static void a() {
        cout << "A::a" << endl;
    }
public:
    void b() {
        cout << "A::b" << endl;
        
        a();
    }
};

class B: public A {
protected:
    static void a() {
        cout << "B::a" << endl;
        A::a();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.b();
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dnY5o8WfK

Comment: How would you do this in java? AFAIK there is no way there either to override `static` methods?

Comment: are you confusing `static` with `virtual` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `virtual` keyword instead of `static` as shown below, since `static` in this context means that there is no implicit `this` parameter for the non-static member function `a`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
    virtual void a() { //note the virtual keyword
        cout << "A::a" << endl;
    }
public:
    void b() {
        cout << "A::b" << endl;
        
        a();
    }
};

class B: public A {
protected:
    virtual void a() {//note the virtual keyword
        cout << "B::a" << endl;
        A::a();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.b();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/n-VroQzkG):

```
A::b
B::a
A::a
```

By using `virtual` we're making the member function `a` to be a **virtual member funciton**.

Comment: I used `static` consciously.

Comment: @PiotrZych Ok, so do you already know what `static` means(in this context) as i explained in my answer? If yes, then can you tell why have you chosen `static` instead of `virtual` when `virtual` is more suitable for your purpose?

Comment: Let's assume, I cannot modify `A` class. Example was created by simplifying specific problem. I want to prepare unit test but I have to mock some things between A::b and A::a execution.

Comment: @PiotrZych It seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). But given your original question(and description), i think `virtual` is what you need to use.

Comment: Indeed. But I have to understand where is the root.